# No FileSystem for scheme:hdfs

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

Im new to hadoop and started executing simple fileread java programme and got ioexception.Added plugins in pom.xml and even tried by adding LocalFileSystem and DistributedFileSystem values in property still seeing the same ioexception.

Comment: Please show your POM and your code

Comment: package com.hdfs_java_api;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
public class HadoopFileSystemCat {package com.hdfs_java_api;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
public class HadoopFileSystemCat {

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String uri = "hdfs://localhost:50070/Basi/Haddoop.txt";
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri),conf);
  InputStream in = null;
  try{
   in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
   IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
  }
  finally {
   IOUtils.closeStream(in);
  }

 }

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>hdfs_java_api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>hdfs_java_api</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

Comment: i have added this property i the POM ile with oth properties like Haoop common,yarn common,map red client & common

<dependency>
  <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0_111</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and format that code? Plus, I don't see any a Hadoop dependency mentioned in  what you show